# Package's target is .NETCore but mine is .NETCoreApp

Tags: c#, .net-5

I want to add a package to my project, but it says:

```
error: Package PixivCS 0.4.4 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package PixivCS 0.4.4 supports: netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
```

Then I tried to change the target framework using the properties option in VisualStudio, but the `.NET 5.0` is the only option
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxI4l.png)

If change the `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` in .csproj to `<TargetFramework>netcore50</TargetFramework>`

```
Error   NETSDK1013  The TargetFramework value 'netcore50' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.   HelloWorld  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.3.20216.6\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 100
```

How can I change the framework of my project form `net5.0` to `netcore50` so I can use that package?

What's the difference between `.NETCore` and `.NETCoreApp`?

Comment: Between previews 2 and 3 of .NET 5, the Target Framework Moniker (TFM) changed from `netcoreapp5.0` to `net5.0`. `net5.0` is the TFM that will be used going forwards, so you will either need to downgrade to preview 2 to use PixivCS or wait until PixivCS builds a new version that supports the `net5.0` TFM.

Comment: `netcore50` is actually a completely different TFM from `netcoreapp5.0`. [Target Frameworks Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks) suggests that it is a much older TFM, targeted at Windows Store applications.

Answer (score 0):

Update with new version. Please go here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/  and update your VS. Then try to replace:

> `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>

    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```